# Лайтбокс - чи є український відповідник

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова

Є таке речення російською: "Лайтбокс представляет собой короб с подсветкой изнутри." Перекладаючи, дуже не хочеться транслітерувати англійське слово на кшталт російської практики створення неологізмів. Чи доречним буде словосполучення "світна коробка" враховуючи, що "світний короб" мав би бути з лози або лубу. Є ще діалектне слово шабатура, за тлумачним словником,

> **ШАБАТУ́РА**, и, жін., діал. Скринька, коробка.
>
> **КОРО́БКА**, и, жін.
>
> 1. Невелике вмістище різної форми з картону, пластмаси, фанери тощо, звичайно з кришкою.
> 2. спец. Вмістище для різних механізмів, приладів тощо.

За російсько-українським словником А.Кримського,

> **Коро́бка** – 
>   1) коро́бка, (из луба) ко́зуб, козу́бка, козубе́ць (-бця́), козубня́ (-ні́), ум. козубе́нька, (из лозы с глиною) сту́жка, (из берестовой коры) берестя́нка, **(картонка, футляр) шабату́рка**, (жестянка) пу́шка.

Comment: Мені здається, що «світний короб» або «світна коробка» — найкраще, що можна придумати (всі [варіанти на SlovoTvir](//slovotvir.org.ua/words/laitboks), на мій погляд, являють собою повну маячню). Але от чи доречно використовувати це замість уже [більш-менш відомого «лайтбокс»](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=лайтбокс) — не знаю. Хоча [«світний короб» теж хтось вживає](//www.olx.ua/uk/obyavlenie/svtniy-korob-vivska-b-v-dlya-reklami-magazinu-abo-nshogo-IDxxoWk.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для пошуку влучних відповідників варто використовувати сайт Словотвір. [Тут](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/laitboks) маємо такі варіанти перекладу слова "lightbox" - "світлова реклама" (адже згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81): "Лайтбокс — дуже ефективний і відносно недорогий рекламний носій") або також "корбосвіт".

Answer (score -1):

[Коментар на фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/1555059764620064?comment_id=1555270477932326), з яким я частково згоден:

> Лайтбокс є терміном, тому не перекладається. Переклад його (або калькування) став би грубою помилкою <…>.
>
> До речі, саме в російській практиці якраз і намагалися неодноразово запобігати «створюванню неологізмів», як се тут називається, перекладаючи, наприклад, «фортепіано» як «тихогром» тощо. Що з цього вийшло, мабуть, зрозуміло.